# How to remove a matplotlib collection

Tags: python, matplotlib, matplotlib-widget

The Python program below plots a random set of 3 points and circles around them according to the `eps` slider value.

When changing the slider value, the circles change.

Also, if two circles touch each other, a segment connecting their centers is  drawn.

**My problem is:** how to remove such segment if the `eps` decreases so there is no intersection anymore?

In resume, how to remove the line collection from the plot?

**MWE**

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.widgets import Slider, Button, RadioButtons
from matplotlib import collections  as mc


# create circles
circles = []
def create_circles(N):
    for i in range(N):
        circles.append(plt.Circle(pts[i], min_distance/10, ec="b", fill=False))
        ax.add_patch(circles[i])

# create edges
def create_edges(eps):
    edges = []
    tmp = np.where(distance_matrix < 2 * eps)
    edges_ij = zip(tmp[0], tmp[1])
    for e in edges_ij:
        if e[0] < e[1]:
            edges.append([pts[e[0]], pts[e[1]]])
    lc = mc.LineCollection(edges, colors='r', linewidths=1)
    ax.add_collection(lc)

# create points
def create_points(N):
    ptsx = np.random.random(N)
    ptsy = np.random.random(N)
    pts = zip(ptsx, ptsy)
    return pts

# create distance matrix
def create_distance_matrix(pts):
    N = len(pts)
    distance_matrix = np.zeros((N, N))
    for i in range(N-1):
        for j in range(i+1,N):
            P = pts[i]
            Q = pts[j]
            distance_matrix[i, j] = np.sqrt((P[0]-Q[0])**2 + (P[1]-Q[1])**2)
            distance_matrix[j, i] = distance_matrix[i, j]
    max_distance = np.max(distance_matrix)
    min_distance = np.min(distance_matrix[distance_matrix > 0])
    return min_distance, max_distance, distance_matrix

# when epsilon slider changes
def update_eps(val):
    eps1 = eps_slider.val
    create_edges(eps1)
    for i in range(len(circles)):
        circles[i].set_radius(eps1) 
    fig.canvas.draw_idle()

axis_color = 'lightgoldenrodyellow'
bullet_size = 4

xmin, xmax = 0, 1
ymin, ymax = 0, 1
delta = .2
xlim = [xmin-delta, xmax+delta]
ylim = [ymin-delta, ymax+delta]

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
plt.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.25)
ax.axis([xlim[0], xlim[1], ylim[0], ylim[1]])
ax.set_aspect("equal")

N_0 = 3
N_max = 10

pts = create_points(N_0)
min_distance, max_distance, distance_matrix = create_distance_matrix(pts)
create_circles(N_0)
eps_0 = min_distance / 3

# create sliders
eps_slider_ax  = fig.add_axes([0.25, 0.15, .65, 0.03], facecolor=axis_color)
N_slider_ax = fig.add_axes([0.25, 0.1, 0.65, 0.03], facecolor=axis_color)
eps_slider = Slider(eps_slider_ax, 'eps', min_distance/3, max_distance, valinit=eps_0)
N_slider = Slider(N_slider_ax, 'Num pts', 1, N_max, valinit=2, valfmt="%i")
eps_slider.on_changed(update_eps)

# Draw the initial plot
desenho = ax.scatter([x[0] for x in pts], [x[1] for x in pts], alpha=1, s=bullet_size)
plt.show()
```

Comment: I think this question might be of use to you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19569052/matplotlib-how-to-remove-a-specific-line-or-curve/19571848

Comment: @GILO, let me read. Thanks.